# Why star arguments, but not positional ones, can appear after a keyword argument?

Tags: python

In a Python function call, it is valid to have a star argument after a keyword one as reported by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) and shown by the following valid code that prints `1 2`

```
def f(a, b):
   print(a, b)
f(b=2, *(1,))
```

Nevertheless, it is not valid to have a positional argument after a keyword one as shown by the following call that leads to a `SyntaxError`

```
f(b=2, 1)
```

What is the reason why star arguments, but not positional ones, can appear after a keyword argument ? Why positional and starred argument don't behave the same way while a starred argument is a shortcut for specifying several positional ones?

Comment: You linked the answer yourself - `A consequence of this is that although the *expression syntax may appear after explicit keyword arguments, it is processed before the keyword arguments (and any **expression arguments – see below). `

Comment: +As you can see, your example is different than theirs. In the docs there is `f(a=1, *(2,))` that, because of the evaluation order, fails (`TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'`)

Comment: @h4z3 I understand that it fails according to the documentation. But still I don't understand why ```*expression``` is processed before the keyword arguments and not single positional arguments.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue38560 I also found this short discussion about this, but nothing on "why" it's legal. | `processed before the keyword arguments and not single positional arguments` - ??? The second part here is not what you asked earlier? `*` unpacking in arguments happens during positional argument processing - `*expr` may be between positional arguments (`fun(1, *(2,3), 4)`). Positional arguments are always processed before the keyword arguments, so the "processed before the keyword and not positional" makes no sense?

Comment: @h4z3 I meant "*expression is processed before the keyword arguments and single positional arguments are processed after keyword arguments if they appear after it the arguments list"